# Fullcalendar in Django - multiple calendars

Tags: html, django, django-models, fullcalendar, django-3.0

I suppose that this is a simple task, but I just can't figure it out on my own.

I have a Calendar model, Events model, and CalendarGroups model, and a form, with the Event model.

What I need, is a calendar selection, during the event creation.

So, the User wants to add an event and to select a calendar for that event, and the event will be displayed only on that calendar.

For now, I made two calendars from the admin panel, and I can render those two, and they have different ID's, which I can see from the page source.

But when I try to add an event, and when I choose a calendar with ID = 1 for example, the event gets rendered on both calendars(needs to be rendered only on the calendar with ID=1).

This is my models.py :

```
class CalendarGroups(models.Model):
    GRP_CALS = (
        ('Optika', 'Optika'),
        ('Bakar', 'Bakar'),
        ('DTH', 'DTH'),
        ('Supernova', 'Supernova'),
        ('Test', 'Test'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=155, choices=GRP_CALS, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Calendar Group'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Calendar Groups'

#####################################################################################
class Calendar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=155, blank=True, null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(CalendarGroups, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Calendar'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Calendars'

#####################################################################################
class Events(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('zakazan', 'Zakazan'),
        ('otkazan', 'Otkazan')
    )

    event_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    event_comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=155, choices=STATUS)
    zakazan = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    opp_eluid = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    calendar = models.ForeignKey(Calendar, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Event'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Events'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.event_name)
```

This is my views.py :

```
def events(request):
    all_events = Events.objects.all()
    get_event_types = Events.objects.only('event_type')
    calendars = Calendar.objects.all()

    if request.GET:
        event_arr = []
        if request.GET.get('event_type') == "all":
            all_events = Events.objects.all()
        else:
            all_events = Events.objects.filter(event_type__icontains=request.GET.get('event_type'))

        for i in all_events:
            event_sub_arr = {}
            event_sub_arr['id'] = i.event_id
            event_sub_arr['calendar'] = i.calendar
            event_sub_arr['calendar_id'] = i.calendar.id
            event_sub_arr['title'] = i.event_name
            start_date = datetime.strptime(str(i.start_date.date()), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
            end_date = datetime.strptime(str(i.end_date.date()), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
            event_sub_arr['start'] = start_date
            event_sub_arr['end'] = end_date
            event_arr.append(event_sub_arr)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(event_arr))

    context = {
        "calendars": calendars,
        "events": all_events,
        "get_event_types": get_event_types,

    }
    return render(request, 'main/selectable.html', context)


def add_event(request, pk):
    opp = get_object_or_404(OpportunityList, pk=pk) # This is the lead which will be schaduled for. Nothing to do with this question.
    events = Events.objects.all() # All the events scheduled so far.

    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
    opp_locked = get_object_or_404(Locked, pk=pk) # Locked lead. Just ignore it.
    form = ZakaziForma() # Scheduling form(simple form with the model fields)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ZakaziForma(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            event = Events.objects.create(
                start_date=form.cleaned_data['start_date'],
                end_date=form.cleaned_data['end_date'],
                event_name=form.cleaned_data['event_name'],
                added_by=user,
                event_comment=form.cleaned_data['event_comment'],
                status=form.cleaned_data['status'],
                zakazan=True,
                opp_eluid=int(opp_locked.locked_eluid.eluid),
                calendar=form.cleaned_data['calendar'],
            )
            opp_locked.is_locked = False
            opp_locked.zakazan = True
            opp_locked.save()
            event.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Uspešno ste zakazali termin za ' + opp_locked.locked_comment)
            return redirect('opportunity:optika')
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'opp': opp,
        'events': events
    }
    return render(request, 'opportunity/detalji/zakazi.html', context)
```

This is the form for adding events

```
from django import forms
from tempus_dominus.widgets import DateTimePicker

from .models import Events


class ZakaziForma(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Events
        fields = ['event_name', 'event_comment', 'status', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'calendar', 'opp_eluid']

        labels = {
            'event_name': 'Naziv Posla:',
            'event_comment': 'Komentar:',
            'status': 'Status:',
            'start_date': 'Početak:',
            'end_date': 'Završetak:',
            'calendar': 'Kalendar'
        }

        widgets = {
            'start_date': DateTimePicker(options={'useCurrent': True, 'collapse': False},
                                         attrs={'icon-toggle': True, }),
            'end_date': DateTimePicker(options={'useCurrent': True, 'collapse': False}),
            'opp_eluid': forms.HiddenInput()
        }
```

The html for adding events, with the form and calendar preview. Calendar preview doesn't work. It doesn't render at all. It renders the form only.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %} Zakazivanje {% endblock %}

{% block content_row %}
    <div style="display: flex;" class="flex-container">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <form method="post" action="{% url 'main:add_event' opp.pk %}">
                        {{ form|crispy }}
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Potvrdi</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            {% if calendar %}
                {% for cal in calendar %}
                    <script>
                        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                            let calendarEl = document.getElementById('{{ cal.id }}');
                            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                            let calendar1 = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                                minTime: "07:00:00",
                                maxTime: "22:00:00",
                                businessHours: {
                                    startTime: '08:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
                                    endTime: '21:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
                                },
                                height: 'auto',
                                locale: 'sr',
                                plugins: ['dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'interaction'],
                                defaultView: 'timeGridThreeDay',
                                header: {
                                    left: 'today',
                                    center: '',
                                    right: 'dayGridWeek,timeGridThreeDay'
                                },
                                views: {
                                    timeGridThreeDay: {
                                        type: 'timeGrid',
                                        duration: {days: 3},
                                        buttonText: '3 Dana'
                                    }
                                },
                                navLinks: false, // can click day/week names to navigate views
                                editable: false,
                                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                                eventTextColor: 'black',
                                events: [
                                    {% for i in events %}
                                        {
                                            title: "{{ i.event_name}}",
                                            start: '{{ i.start_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}T{{ i.start_date|time:"H:i" }}',
                                            end: '{{ i.end_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}T{{ i.end_date|time:"H:i" }}',

                                        },
                                    {% endfor %}
                                ]
                            });

                            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                            calendar1.render();
                            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                        })
                        ;
                    </script>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            <style>

                .calendarMine {
                    max-width: 400px;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                }
            </style>

            <div style="display: flex;" class="flex-container">
                {% for cal in calendar %}
                    <div class="calendarMine" id='{{ cal.id }}'></div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock content_row %}
```

This is my calendar page. Both calendars are rendered, but the events are on both calendars.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %} Kalendar {% endblock title %}



{% block content_row %}
    <!--------------------------------------------- FULLCALENDAR LINKS ---------------------------------------------->
    {% include 'main/partials/_link_fullcalendar.html' %}
    <!--------------------------------------------- FULLCALENDAR LINKS END ------------------------------------------>

    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                    <strong>Uspešno!</strong> {{ message }}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if calendars %}
        {% for cal in calendars %}
            <script>
                document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                    let calendarEl = document.getElementById('{{ cal.id }}');
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    let calendar1 = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                        minTime: "07:00:00",
                        maxTime: "22:00:00",
                        businessHours: {
                            startTime: '08:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
                            endTime: '21:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
                        },
                        height: 'auto',
                        locale: 'sr',
                        plugins: ['dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'interaction'],
                        defaultView: 'timeGridThreeDay',
                        header: {
                            left: 'today',
                            center: '',
                            right: 'dayGridWeek,timeGridThreeDay'
                        },
                        views: {
                            timeGridThreeDay: {
                                type: 'timeGrid',
                                duration: {days: 3},
                                buttonText: '3 Dana'
                            }
                        },
                        navLinks: false, // can click day/week names to navigate views
                        editable: false,
                        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                        eventTextColor: 'black',
                        events: [
                            {% for i in events %}
                                {
                                    title: "{{ i.event_name}}",
                                    start: '{{ i.start_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}T{{ i.start_date|time:"H:i" }}',
                                    end: '{{ i.end_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}T{{ i.end_date|time:"H:i" }}',

                                },
                            {% endfor %}
                        ]
                    });
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    calendar1.render();
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                })
                ;
            </script>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    <div style="display: flex;" class="container">
        {% for cal in calendars %}
            <div class="container" id='{{ cal.id }}'></div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <!---------------------------------------------- FULLCALENDAR SCRIPT----------------------------------------------->
    {% include 'main/partials/_fullcalendar_script.html' %}
    <!---------------------------------------------- FULLCALENDAR SCRIPT END ------------------------------------------>
{% endblock %}
```

This is a page source:

```
<script>
                document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                    let calendarEl = document.getElementById('1');
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    let calendar1 = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                        minTime: "07:00:00",
                        maxTime: "22:00:00",
                        businessHours: {
                            startTime: '08:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
                            endTime: '21:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
                        },
                        height: 'auto',
                        locale: 'sr',
                        plugins: ['dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'interaction'],
                        defaultView: 'timeGridThreeDay',
                        header: {
                            left: 'today',
                            center: '',
                            right: 'dayGridWeek,timeGridThreeDay'
                        },
                        views: {
                            timeGridThreeDay: {
                                type: 'timeGrid',
                                duration: {days: 3},
                                buttonText: '3 Dana'
                            }
                        },
                        navLinks: false, // can click day/week names to navigate views
                        editable: false,
                        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                        eventTextColor: 'black',
                        events: [

                                {
                                    id: "57",
                                    calendar: "Test Kalendar",
                                    calendar_id: "1",
                                    title: "Test ID",
                                    start: '2020-01-14T12:00',
                                    end: '2020-01-14T13:00',

                                },

                        ]
                    });
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    calendar1.render();
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                })
                ;
            </script>

            <script>
                document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                    let calendarEl = document.getElementById('4');
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    let calendar1 = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                        minTime: "07:00:00",
                        maxTime: "22:00:00",
                        businessHours: {
                            startTime: '08:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
                            endTime: '21:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
                        },
                        height: 'auto',
                        locale: 'sr',
                        plugins: ['dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'interaction'],
                        defaultView: 'timeGridThreeDay',
                        header: {
                            left: 'today',
                            center: '',
                            right: 'dayGridWeek,timeGridThreeDay'
                        },
                        views: {
                            timeGridThreeDay: {
                                type: 'timeGrid',
                                duration: {days: 3},
                                buttonText: '3 Dana'
                            }
                        },
                        navLinks: false, // can click day/week names to navigate views
                        editable: false,
                        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                        eventTextColor: 'black',
                        events: [

                                {
                                    id: "57",
                                    calendar: "Test Kalendar",
                                    calendar_id: "1",
                                    title: "Test ID",
                                    start: '2020-01-14T12:00',
                                    end: '2020-01-14T13:00',

                                },

                        ]
                    });
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    calendar1.render();
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                })
                ;
            </script>



    <div style="display: flex;" class="container">

            <div class="container" id='1'></div>

            <div class="container" id='4'></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: where is the client-side code for adding events? It's unclear how you are sending new event data to the server, or whether/if you are attempting to send the ID of the calendar in that request. And I am not really a python programmer, but from what I can make out from it, in your "add_event" procedure, I don't see any code which tries to get the ID of the calendar? If I'm mistaken, please point it out specifically.

Comment: ...so, if you are not differentiating between the calendars when adding events, it's a bit unclear how you'd expect it to do that when rendering them, either.

Comment: I changed my code, and added a full source for all the actions.

Comment: In my form for adding events, user has an option to select calendar, which is a field in Events model, and foreign key of Calendar class.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense. So now, you need to read the value of `calendar` for each event when you are outputting the events, and decide if that event belongs with that calendar, or not. Chris's answer below shows a likely approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments, you are not differentiating between calendars when loading your events.

One possibility could be doing this when looping through your events. So you could rewrite the "events" part in your calendar script

```
    events: [
      {% for i in events %}
          {% if i.calendar_id == cal.id %}
              {
                 title: "{{ i.event_name}}",
                 start: '{{ i.start_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}T{{ i.start_date|time:"H:i" }}',
                 end: '{{ i.end_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}T{{ i.end_date|time:"H:i" }}',

              },
           {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    ]
```

Other possibilities could include doing the differentiation your view